# Iterate and compare values in map<string, vector<string>> c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, boost-filesystem

I have written a program in c++17 using the boost::filesystem library that takes a path as an argument and returns a map:

```
map<string, vector<string>>
```

where each key is a directory (boost::filesystem::path converted to string), and each file in each directory is pushed to the value vector.

First, I create a vector of paths from the path given as an argument:

```
// Method to create vector of paths
vector<path> InToVecsOne(path p, vector<path> v1)
{
  for(auto entry : recursive_directory_iterator(p))
  {
    if(is_directory(entry))
    {
      v1.push_back(entry);
    }
  }
  return v1;
}
```

Then, I create the map using the vector as follows:

```
// Function takes a vector of paths and returns map of key-value pair path-vector<string>
map<string,vector<string>> FileMap(vector<path> v1, 
map<string,vector<string>> m, vector<string> v2)
{
  for(auto p : v1)
  {
    // iterate over each entry in path p
    for(auto entry : directory_iterator(p)) 
    {
      if(is_regular_file(entry) == true)
      {
        // add file to vector<string>
        v2.push_back(basename(entry) + " "); 
      }
    }
    // convert path to pathname (DirX) string
    string pathname = basename(p); 
    m.insert(make_pair(pathname, v2));
    v2.erase(v2.begin(), v2.end()); // remove contents after iterating
  }
  return m;
}
```

Using my sandbox directory as a test path, I get the following output when printing the contents of my map:

```
DirA: Z X Y 
DirB: Z X Y 
DirBB: X Y YY 
DirC: Z 
DirCC: ZZ X Y YY
```

As noticeable, the keys are DirA, DirB, DirBB, etc. and the values are Z, X, Y etc.

What I want to do now is to transform things so that my output looks like:

```
X : DirA, DirB, DirBB, DirCC
Y : DirA, DirB, DirBB, DirCC
```

etc.

I think the best way for this would be either to:
1. re-write the map method, or
2. iterate over the contents in the map, compare if the value is associated with a key and add this value to a new data structure.

I am not sure of which would be easier, or how the second one would look like, and hence would need some advice.

Thanks.

---

Extension:

Following comment to create a map of filename-path pairs, I encountered a new problem after creating this new map from the old map above. My function is as follows:

```
// Make new map where file is key, and dir is value. m1 is old map, m2 is new map
map<string,vector<string>> FinalMap(map<string,vector<string>> m1, 
map<string,vector<string>> m2, vector<string> dirnames)
{
  // iterate over each key
  for(map<string,vector<string>>::const_iterator it = m1.begin(); it != m1.end(); ++it)
  {
    string dirname = it->first;
    dirnames.push_back(dirname);

    vector<string> files = it->second;
    // iterate over elements in vector<string> files
    for(auto i : files)
    {
      m2.insert(make_pair(i, dirnames));
    }
    dirnames.erase(dirnames.begin(), dirnames.end());
  }
  return m2;
}
```

However, now my output is as follows:

```
X : DirA
Y : DirA
YY : DirBB
Z : DirA
ZZ : DirCC
```

I need it to be:

```
X : DirA, DirB, DirBB
```

etc. given that the file X is in DirA, DirB and DirBB. Therefore, I have to alter the function FileMap.

Comment: You have a map of directories to file names. You need a map of file names to directories. That's pretty much it.

Comment: What do you need an ordered map of directories' files? Are you sure you're not trying to optimize the wrong thing?

Comment: @WhozCraig I know what you mean, but I'm stuck on conceptualising how that solution would look like.

Comment: Not sure what the disconnect it. The most minimal solution would be to keep everything you have now, but then enumerate the map of folders to vector of files, and for every file name in each folder, stuff that filename/folder pair into another map of string to vector<string>, this time representing file names mapped to the folders that contain them. The result should be what you seek.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the advice. Please see the edit I made. I now encountered the problem that when I am populating the vector<string> with directory names, it only adds one directory using push_back(dirname)... Guess I will need to change the algorithm.

Comment: Unrelated to your mapping, your code seems slightly strange. You accept parameters by value to fill, rather than use locals. You can also simplify the filling of your map to `for(auto entry : recursive_directory_iterator(path)) if (entry.is_regular_file()) insert(result, entry.path().filename(), entry.path().parent_path());`, you don't need `InToVecsOne`

Comment: In that case, result would be a local containing what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt in doing as described in comments is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> 
FinalMap(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>const& folderToFiles)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> fileToFolders;

    for (auto const& pr : folderToFiles)
    {
        for (auto const& file : pr.second)
            fileToFolders[file].push_back(pr.first);
    }

    return fileToFolders;
}
```

That's it. This enumerates each mapping of folder-to-filesand creates a new mapping of file-to-folders. I'm pretty sure, was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So much easier like this <3

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`boost::bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html) instead of a std::map, and get both Dir -> File and File -> Dir lookups.

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
using file_map = boost::bimap<std::string, boost::bimaps::multi_set_of<std::string>>;
```

You would then insert a `pathname, filename` pair, rather than gathering a `vector` of filenames to associate with a path.

Note that if you are only using the base name of a directory, you may get duplicates. Store either the whole path, or a `multi_set_of` on both sides.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did not know of bimap until now, and realise it might have saved me time. However, I am short on time and will try to avoid learning the documentation for bimap atm.

Comment: @Mattia If you have a `boost::bimap<dir, multi_set_of<file>>  fmap`, then `fmap.left` acts like a `std::multi_map<dir, file>`, and `fmap.right` acts like a `std::map<file, dir>`. That's all you need to know

Comment: Thanks! Was just thinking of using a multimap now.

Comment: A simpler solution is to populate a separate `set<string, vector<string>>` .. or ideally a `multiset<string, string>`, which actually then gets you pretty close to what the bimap is doing. The bimap has its advantages (particularly in space requirements) but is a little harder to use right.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I prefer `bimap` over a pair of `map`s because it automatically keeps both sides in sync

Comment: @Caleth It certainly has its benefits, and I've made plenty of use of them accordingly! But they _are_ more complex to use. Particularly consider some of the perhaps surprising semantics when it comes to insert-and-replace operations, which don't work the same as with standard containers.